# Why is my fancybox image overflowing it's borders at the bottom?

Tags: jquery, css

I've been adding jQuery to a fancybox image and now for some reason when I open the image it overflows the fancybox borders at the bottom for some reason.
Can anyone help me and tell me why this is?

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_image").fancybox();
});
```

This makes the image overflow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_image").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function() {
            this.outer.append("read more");
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        afterShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-image").wrap($("<a />", {
                href: $(this.element).data('target'),
                target: ""
            }));
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Then logic would dictate that wrapping the `.fancybox-image` in an `a` is causing your problem.

Comment: Could I create a div and wrap that instead?